# Foxx.queues is undefined

Tags: arangodb

I am trying to utilize the Job-Queue functionality of arangodb.

```
var Foxx = require("org/arangodb/foxx"),
controller = new Foxx.Controller(applicationContext),
Repository = require("org/arangodb/foxx").Repository,
console = require("console"),
arangodb = require("org/arangodb");

var queue = Foxx.queues.create('my-queue');
```

I am getting "TypeError: Foxx.queues is undefined"

I was working on 2.2.6 version but then I upgraded to 2.5 (assuming it was a version problem) but same problem.
Do I have to install it separately ?

Comment: No, the Foxx queues are available by default in 2.4 and 2.5. There is no need to install anything. They are not available in 2.2 however. Foxx queues can be used from within a Foxx route and on the server side in general. Please note that Foxx features cannot be used from the ArangoShell and the web interface (JS shell).

Comment: I added more code to the question. What could be the reason for the error. I have more code below the creation of the queue and everything works when I comment out queue creation.

Comment: Ok. I missed last line of your answer. I created the queue and job inside a Foxx route and it worked. ! Thanks !

Comment: One quick question. I have 2 databases. Should I use different names in both queues ? or queues are database specific and therefore I can use the same name.

Comment: Queue information is stored in a database-specific collection (`_queues`) and should thus be database-specific. However, there is a cache for queues which does not take into account queue's database-specificity. This is fixed in 2.6. To be on the safe-side, I suggest using database-specific queue names per database until then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stj explained in the comments you don't need to install Foxx queues separately. You have them by default since version 2.4.

As you are working with version 2.2.6 you need to update ArangoDB to a higher version (at least 2.4) if you want to use Foxx queues.

Comment: I was able to get it to working. But, I have an another problem. I have developed an application which is deployed on 2 databases (same arangodb instance), I can add jobs to both queues (queues and job type have different names for both databases) but job is executed only on one queue. Rest of the jobs remains as pending.

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal If the answer solves your original question, could you mark it as accepted and create a new question for your other question? The two aren't really related and comments aren't the best place to answer follow-up questions.